# How to override initial ViewController on First Run thru AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following code to detect whether the app is running for the first time:

```
    // Detect First Launch

    let firstLaunch = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("FirstLaunch")
    if firstLaunch  {
        print("Not first launch.")
        Show()
    }
    else {
        print("First launch, setting NSUserDefault.")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
    }
```

I am using the following function to show the ViewController:

```
func Show(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“myViewController”) as! MyViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I put both code under: `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {`

However, when I build and run the app, the initial view controller is shown as if nothing happened. I want “myViewController” to be shown FIRST (during the app’s FIRST EVER LAUNCH on the device.) After that first launch, however, the “myViewController” won’t be shown anymore, unless the user uninstalls and freshly reinstalls the app.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: are you looking to present the `myViewController` and then dismiss it to the view controller that is normally the root or you would like to replace the usual root?

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier, I would need the first option. I am looking to present the `myViewController` and dismiss it to show the actual root, and not to replace it. I need to invoke this ONLY during the first launch..

Comment: @pinkBlossoms7 when you installed the app, firstLaunch is `false`,  app will not call `Show`, the `myViewController` will show except your first launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to show the custom screen on first launch and then dismiss it, I would run this code in your normal root VC's `viewWillAppear(animated:Bool)` method

**EDIT:**

Yes, you will have to modify the code a bit. For example, like so:

```
func Show(){
    guard let sb = storyboard else { return }
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“myViewController”) as! MyViewController
    navigationController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error in         `self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` it says `//viewController has no member 'window'`.. How should I replace it?

Comment: I replaced it with `presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` and it worked, thanks!

Comment: glad it worked, but take a look at my edited answer. better way to get your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the value to user defaults, you have to save it using the `synchronize` method. This method is invoked periodically buy the system, but if you didn't synchronize before it was called, your value isn't saved.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

---

Documentation of `synchronize`from to Apple docs :

> Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.